# Primer Like swipable cards

Tags: android, swipe

Google has recently launched app called [Primer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.primer&hl=en). I want to make swipable cards like it. Found several options on git like [SwipeStack](https://github.com/flschweiger/SwipeStack)

But the main problem is this when a card is swiped away there is no option to show it back. But primer does it when user swipe downwards.

How can I achieve that please let me know if there is any other library providing such functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use a `ViewPager` populated programmatically with pages containing your cards.

Comment: I want to do it through ViewPager Transformation, @FarbodSalamat-Zadeh can give some link or other hint on how to move forward with this?Currently I'm Looking at ViewPager.PagerTransfomation doc.